# How to search the ArrayList for a Employee name (searched only for last name )

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

If a data file is given to you which contains Employees First and last names, and their salaries, how to create an array list of that data? In addition, how to create a method that searches the ArrayList for an Employee name (User-entered LAST name) and another method to search the ArrayList for all Employees that make  more than a user-entered amount per week??

Comment: you need to share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get the file in some specific format, for instance csv.
If you don´t, that´s basically impossible. You need anything to seperate the data.

I´d create a class containing first name, last name and salaries. If the first name does not matter to you at all you might also store it in a HashMap, it would make search easy but you´d get issues if some last name is in there twice since one would be overwritten.

1. Create a class with required fields
2. Create an ArrayList
3. Read the file, create an object for every entry in the file and add this object to the array

Searching for lastname:
 Loop through the list with an foreach loop and compare the lastname to the search string. If it matches -> do whatever you need, System.out.printLine for instance.

Searching for salary:
 Loop through the list with an foreach loop and check if the salary of the current object is >= your reference salary. Then print it or add it to another array if needed

You might also check this if you want to use the filter() function in Java 8 but it will create a stream in the process. https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/

The approach you use basically depends on the size of the file. If you´re talking about many records in the file then there are better approches

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file looks like the following:

```
First Last Salary
----- ---- -----
John  Doe   78
Brad  Snow  98
Bill  Rosnow 101
```

I would make some kind of data structure to hold each line of data, like an Employee class object

```
public class Employee {
    private String First;
    private String Last;
    private double salary;
    // constructor, setters, getters down below
}
```

Then you would read each line of data and store the contents into the object, and add it to your ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Employee> dataArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
// pseudo code here
while(Not End of File) {
    // Parse file line contents and separate into local variables
    Employee dataLine = new Employee(firstNameFromFile, LastNameFromFile, salaryFromFile);
    dataArray.add(dataLine);
}
```

That is how I would store the data from the file into the ArrayList. Now for searching your array, it depends on how efficient you want your algorithm to be. You can do a simple linear search, which is O(n), by iterating over each object in the array list. One can do this by the following for loop:

```
for(Employee employee : dataArray) {
    if(employee.getLastName() == searchingName) return employee; 
}
```

Now one could do the same for a specified salary, but you could store the found Employee objects into a another ArrayList; this way you can have all the employees whose salary are above the specified amount:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeesFound = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for(Employee employee : dataArray) { // Don't forget that dataArray holds all the Employee objects
    if(employee.getSalary() > userSpecifiedSalary) employeesFound.add(employee); 
}
return employeesFound;
```

Hope this helps!